# Pulling Data and Quantities from a table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

What formulas could I use if I wanted the lower part of this on its own. A user would enter the machine number, and it would list the cams required for that machine, as well as quantities required. HOWEVER, if only ONE cam is needed for each product, it would return 1 for QTY but yet, if it repeats within a product row it would have to add to that quantity. See the example at the bottom and what it should return as cams and quantities by entering in the machine #.

[image: Example]

Comment: What version of Excel does the user have?

Comment: It is excel 2013 currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel-365 then try below formulas.

```
C8=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER(C2:E4,B2:B4=B8))&"</s></t>","//s"))
D8=SUM(--(MMULT({1,1,1},--($C$2:$E$4=C8))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: So I found out, it's not such a new version...I am using office 2013...any chance I could get help on this code? The 2nd Sum equation works just fine, but need to pull data from the chart a different way. I also have a larger data set, so there are multiple machine numbers listed so it will have to pull ONLY that of the machine number which you request

Comment: So I found out, it's not such a new version...I am using office 13...any chance I could get help on this code? The 2nd Sum eq works just fine, but need to pull data from the chart a diff way. I also have a larger data set, so there are multiple machine numbers listed so it will have to pull ONLY that of the machine number which you request

Also, if I have a large data set with multiple machine numbers, how would this 2nd formula react if you want to exclude everything that doesn't meet the machine number requirement? Can I implement this restriction with the machine number within this calc?